# Solidity coverage report , need help as a beginner

Tags: solidity-coverage

I have a NFT project in truffle for which I have written some tests but need to make a "coverage report".

I have no knowledge how to go about it .

Is there any reading material or any posts that can guide me ?

Thanks

Ashish

Answer (score 2):

you can use https://github.com/sc-forks/solidity-coverage

after installing npm package, you can add it to config like following:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {...},
  plugins: ["solidity-coverage"]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error , ``` solidity-coverage listed as a plugin, but not found in global or local node modules```. Do I have to do some modification in package.json manually?

Comment: yes @Ashishkumar, you need to first install the node module of the plugin